# Select object by part of their material name

Tags: python, materials, objects

I have difficulties trying to select a bunch of object by part of their materialname.
eg. i've got some objects and 2 of them have a material that contains the word "text". 
In the end I want to parent these object to an empty and then move them to a hidden layer.

i've tried the following code, but this gives errors.

```
textmat = [mat for mat in bpy.data.materials if fnmatch.fnmatchcase(mat.material, "*text*")]


obj = bpy.data.objects
for ob in obj:
    if ob.type == 'MESH':
        for m in ob.material_slots:
            if m.material == textmat:
                ob.select = False
```

i'm obviously doing something wrong, but my python skills are still limited

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, even a [simple condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361253/how-to-determine-whether-a-substring-is-in-a-different-string) should do the trick.

```
import bpy

obj_list = []

for o in bpy.data.objects:
    for m in o.material_slots:
        if "text" in m.name:
            obj_list.append(o)

print (obj_list)
```

I suggest  add the items to a [set instead of a list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) — avoids adding multiple entries of identical objects (in case there are multiple materials per object containing `text` as substring in their name).

```
import bpy

obj_set = set()

for o in bpy.data.objects:
    for m in o.material_slots:
        if "test" in m.name:
            obj_set.add(o)

if len(obj_set):
    bpy.ops.object.add(type='EMPTY', location=(0,0,0))
    emtpy_obj = bpy.context.object
    for o in obj_set:
        o.parent = emtpy_obj
```

Comment: Perhaps append `o` , `if len([m for m in o.material_slots if "text" in m.name])` to avoid multiples.

Comment: Yep, might be a good thing. I also thought about creating a set instead of a list to keep it clean. Let's wait for the OP... Thank you @batFINGER

Comment: thanks, both work. Which one would you recommend and what's the exact difference..

Comment: @AndreBredeweg What do you mean? Set vs. list?

Comment: Yes indeed, a set vs list.